# How to run powershell script (.ps1) in windows terminal powershell tab?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I have tried making the script open with windows terminal (wt.exe) but it displays the error :

```
[error 0x800700c1 when launching `"C:\Users\hjdom\OneDrive\Desktop\All desktop stuff\Python Game\RunGame.ps1"']
```

I really need it to run in the windows terminal because it allows you to keep typing commands after the script is over. I am using the script to run a python file.

this is what the ps1 script contains:

```
python ./pythonfiles/startgame.py
```

***Thanks so much!
-BlueFalconHD***

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full `wt.exe` command line and clarify where you're calling it _from_.

Answer (score 10):

The Windows Terminal (wt.exe) is not a command shell.

It is a host for command shells (powershell, bash, cmd, python, perl, etc.). You have to tell WT.exe which to use, to call your script.

Example - cmd.exe or via the WinKey Run:

Type:

```
wt d:\temp\hello.ps1
```

this will fail with...

```
[error 0x800700c1 when launching `d:\temp\hello.ps1']
```

... even though Windows Terminal launches with whatever default shell is in your WT settings.

Now do this...

```
wt.exe powershell D:\Scripts\hello.ps1
```

... this works, because you told wt.exe which shell to use to execute your script.

**Update as per your comment.**

> but then how do I prevent the terminal from closing after the script
> is done running?

Your target shell needs to provide a method for that. Powershell (Windows and Core) provide this via the `-NoExit` switch.

```
powershell /?

PowerShell[.exe] [-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]
    [-NoLogo] [-NoExit] [-Sta] [-Mta] [-NoProfile] [-NonInteractive]
    [-InputFormat {Text | XML}] [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-WindowStyle <style>] [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
    [-ConfigurationName <string>]
    [-File <filePath> <args>] [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
    [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                  | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]

wt.exe powershell -NoProfile -NoLogo -NoExit D:\Scripts\hello.ps1

wt.exe pwsh -NoProfile -NoLogo -NoExit D:\Scripts\hello.ps1
```

If you are calling another shell, bash, python, perl, etc., then they too would need to provide that.

Comment: but then how do I prevent the terminal from closing after the script is done running? I want you to be able to type in commands.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that wants to personalise their PowerShell terminal inside windows terminal or run a script when PowerShell is opened inside windows terminal, you must do the following:

You must run the desired script as an argument passed to PowerShell. In other words, you use the powershell.exe as an medium through which you run the script and not as the medium in which the script is run. This means that once the chosen script finished executing, powershell.exe will stop too because the executable's functionality was passed to the script. In order to prevent this you must pass to the argument the attribute  " PowerShell -NoExit ".

Example:

```
%SystemRoot%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe PowerShell -NoExit %SystemRoot%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\PowerShell_Startup_Ascii_Art.ps1
```

This will prevent PowerShell from closing, once the script finished executing.

Comment: this was the answer I needed!  but I did have to adjust it a bit.  I am using Windows Terminal and this command is for the Command Line in Settings of one of the entries.  The word "PowerShell" had to be removed from the command string.  In my example "py39" is the directory of my virtual environment.

"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoExit %USERPROFILE%\\py39\\Scripts\\Activate.ps1

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. You can check a cool implementation of this in order to customise your Windows Terminal with custom banners on this link if you are interested.                       https://superuser.com/a/1735410/1718628